# How is Peter Parker able to avoid Strange while his astral form is projected?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

In *Spider-Man: No Way Home* (2021), Peter Parker

> steals a relic containing a botched spell from Stephen Strange.

However, when Strange confronts him,

> Strange pushes Parker's astral form out of his body.

Strange then attempts to take back the relic, but

> Peter somehow avoids it while not possessing his body.

<sub><sub>(Jump to 00:35)</sub></sub>

[image: animated GIF of scene]

How is he able to do this? Is it his Spidey-Sense? (*There were suspicious lines wiggling away from his astral form's head during the moment, something I noticed during my rewatch.*)

Comment: It's because of the Peter tingle, I'm sure

Comment: Can't answer this with canonical evidence, but in the comics, Peter's spider-sense allows him to react to threats on instinct alone, i.e. his body can move to avoid something like a bullet, without him consciously choosing to do so. Even with Peter's conscious mind expelled from his body, it presumably retained its ability to function autonomously on some level. For example, I assume his body was still breathing and circulating blood. If that's true, then perhaps it was also capable of a degree of autonomous movement to avoid threats, when prompted by his spider-sense.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I could probably accept that with some evidence as an answer

Comment: Per the [screenplay;](https://deadline.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Spider-Man-No-Way-Home-Read-The-Screenplay.pdf) [But Spider-Man’s Physical Body moves The Box away. Somehow Astral Peter is controlling Spider-Man’s Physical Body!] - ***DR. STRANGE*** *How are you doing that?*
***PETER (ASTRAL BODY)*** *I have no idea...*

Comment: @Valorum Convert it to answer.

Comment: @SatelliteofSin - "Somehow" isn't an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't any clear explanation for this within the movie itself, nor am I aware of any official word on this anywhere else.

In the comics though, Peter's spider-sense is said to trigger an instinctive response from his body, allowing him to avoid danger without making any conscious decisions.

> **Spider-Man's spider-sense is an instinctive response to danger which always triggers his amazing spider-like reflexes in plenty of time to avoid injury!** He moves so fast that he can usually dodge a blow... before it is thrown... which explains why it is so rare for anyone to ever hit him!
>
> **In fact, directed solely by his spider-sense and without making any conscious decisions, our hero has been known to avoid prolonged bursts of machine-gun fire... and computerized, rapidly-fired, random discharges from the Hobgoblin's finger-blaster!**
>
> Of course, since his spider-sense is an instinctive reaction, Spider-Man can disregard it... but that takes a lot of effort, a conscious decision, and a heck of a good reason!
>
> <sub>*[Amazing Spider-Man Annual Vol. 1 #23](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Annual_Vol_1_23)* (September, 1989)</sub>

[image]

As you mentioned, there were transparent, wavy lines around the head of Peter's astral form, in the relevant scene from *Spider-Man: No Way Home*, suggesting that his spider-sense was a factor there.

Also, when Doctor Strange's astral form left his body during his fight with [Lucian Aster](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Lucian_Aster) in *Doctor Strange* (2016), a heart rate monitor indicated that his heart was still beating, despite his physical form and astral form being separate. His heart rate did flatline at one point, due to a stab wound in the chest he'd received during the fight, but [Christine](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Christine_Palmer) was able to use a defibrillator to get it beating again, before his astral form re-entered his body.

This suggests that a person's physical form retains some degree of autonomous function in the MCU, even when separated from their astral form.